# Use quick-view in fancybox

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, fancybox

I using fancybox in my project and now data attribute is gallery

Here is code

```
$(".hotel_gallery").attr("data-fancybox", "gallery")
  .fancybox({
    prevEffect: "none",
    nextEffect: "none",
    closeBtn: true,
    arrows: true,
    beforeShow() {
      this.title = this.src;
    },
    helpers: { title : { type : "inside" } }
  });
```

I want to use quick - view

So I rewrite code like this

```
$(".hotel_gallery").attr("data-fancybox", "quick-view")
  .fancybox({
    prevEffect: "none",
    nextEffect: "none",
    closeBtn: true,
    arrows: true,
    beforeShow() {
      this.title = this.src;
    },
    helpers: { title : { type : "inside" } }
  });
```

But it still have gallery

But here attribute is changed

Here it is

```
<a class="hotel_gallery thumb_a" href="https://aobtravel.s3.amazonaws.com/hotelpictures/004/075/389/LON-91A-2.jpg?1387235916" data-fancybox="quick-view">
```

Where is problem can be?

Comment: What exactly is your issue? Please, create a demo (you can fork any codepen demo).

Comment: My issue in that -  after changing `attr("data-fancybox", "gallery")` to `attr("data-fancybox", "quick-view")` it still show it like gallery @Janis

Comment: But what did you expect? If you create `data-fancybox` attribute with some value (e.g., non-empty), then it will be used to create gallery.

Comment: I need to show it in quick-view style, not default gallery @Janis

Comment: And I not found any docs how to do it @Janis

Comment: What do you mean by "quick-view style"? If you want something like this - https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/JvGjwa - then you need some extra code.

Comment: Yes. I need smth like this @Janis

Answer (score 0):

So after making searches I make write code.

Here is js code

```
 $(".hotel_gallery").attr("data-fancybox", "quick-view")
  .fancybox({
    prevEffect: "none",
    nextEffect: "none",
    closeBtn: true,
    arrows: true,
    beforeShow() {
      this.title = this.src;

    },
    afterLoad(instance, current ){
      if ( instance.group.length > 1 && current.$content ) {
        current.$content.append('<a data-fancybox-next class="button-next" href="javascript:;">→</a><a data-fancybox-previous class="button-previous" href="javascript:;">←</a>');
      }
      current.$content.append('<a data-fancybox-close class="button-close" href="javascript:;">×</a>');
    },
    helpers: { title : { type : "inside" } }
  });
```

It changes default stuff to custom